# Dependency injection with optional parameter in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have multiple components which require the same dependency which requires a string for the constructor. How can I tell angular2 to use a specific instance of the type for DI?

For example:

ChatUsers.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: "chat-users"
})
@View({
    directives: [],
    templateUrl: '/js/components/ChatUsers.html'
})
export class ChatUsers {

    constructor(public currentUser : User) {
    }
}
```

and app.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../libs/typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

import {User} from "User";

// How to create a user, e.g. new User('John') and use it for DI?

@Component({
    selector: 'chat-app'
})
@View({
    directives: [ ],
    template: `
      <div> Some text
      </div>`
})
class ChatApp {
    constructor(public user: User) {
        // do something with user
    }


}
bootstrap(ChatApp, [ User ]);
```

User.ts

```
export class User {
    name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

If run this code, the error is:

> Cannot resolve all parameters for User(?). Make sure they all have
>   valid type or annotations.

I'm using the most recent angular2 version: `2.0.0-alpha.44`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To make dependency optional just use [`@Optional`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.45/modules/angular2/src/core/di/metadata.ts#L71) parameter decorator (see [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UHZ7DYYY91Zu51vKvzjt?p=preview)):

```ts
class User {
  name: string;
  constructor(@Optional() name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

If you want to inject `name` into `User` you have two solutions:

1. Add some `'userName'` provider to app providers and use [`@Inject('userName')`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.45/modules/angular2/src/core/di/metadata.ts#L44) parameter decorator to inject it into `User` (see [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eLeB0SttJD8pf37IBh1m?p=preview)).

```ts
class User {
  name: string;
  constructor(@Inject('userName') name: string) {
      this.name = name;
  }
}
// ...
bootstrap(ChatApp, [
  User, 
  provide('userName', { useValue: 'Bob'})
]);
```

2. Use [`useFactory`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/di/provider.ts#L162) to specifically instantiate your user (see [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GyR183SU8RRIXczp6f7k?p=preview)):

```ts
bootstrap(ChatApp, [
  provide(User, { useFactory: () => new User('John') })
]);
```

Comment: @Best_Where_Gives you should import `@Optional` before using it. Try `import { Optional } from 'angular/core'`. Look at the documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional)